# How to set the height of the barcode as 25mm

Tags: java, itext

As per the API of iText, it is mentioned that we can set the height of the barcode using the method [`public void setBarHeight(float barHeight)`](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/Barcode.html#setBarHeight%28float%29), but it is not mentioned what is the measurement (unit) of the height. I need to have the barcode of height 25mm; so what should be the value passed to the mentioned method?

Answer (score 2):

This is for the class [`BarcodePostnet`](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/BarcodePostnet.html) but it will apply same for others classes that extends [`BarCode`](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/Barcode.html) class.

The unit used is [PostScript Point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_%28typography%29). You shoud pass to the method value **70.86614f** (72 / 25.4 * 25 milimeter = 70.866141732283464566929133858268 PostScript points)

---

**Explanation**

First read docs for the [`BarcodePostnet`](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/BarcodePostnet.html) where you will see

```
    Implements the Postnet and Planet barcodes. The default parameters are:

    n = 72f / 22f; // distance between bars
    x = 0.02f * 72f; // bar width
    barHeight = 0.125f * 72f; // height of the tall bars
    size = 0.05f * 72f; // height of the short bars
    codeType = POSTNET; // type of code
```

Refering to the standard for the [POSTNET barcodes](http://pe.usps.com/text/dmm300/708.htm#1352817)

> 4.2.5 POSTNET Barcode Dimensions and Spacing POSTNET barcodes are subject to these standards for bar dimensions and spacing. Extraneous
>   ink or ink voids must not cause any bar to fail to meet these
>   standards:
>
> a. A full bar must be 0.125 ±0.010 inch high.
>
> b. A half bar must be 0.050 ±0.010 inch high.
>
> c. All bars must be 0.020 ±0.005 inch wide

Therefore you can conclude that default unit is PostScript Point.